# Python Request breaking down a Url

Tags: python, variables, url, request, urllib

I'm trying to just input a URL and have python pull the data needed from the url for the script.

I only really need to isolate 1.2.3 into a variable, 7/8/9 into a variable, and 1.2.3/4/5/6/7 into a variable. The url variables changes and want to be able to update my script easily.
Not really sure if that's possible.

```
Url=https://Thedog.big.com//red/house/large/1.2.3/4/5/6/7/8/9

x = 1.2.3
y = 7/8/9
z = 1.2.3/4/5/6/7
```

Answer (score 0):

That really depends what kind of urls you have, the idea is just find a regular patterns

If all urls are having same structure with change only in values, you can just take out the parts from url string as index:
`a = str(url)[start:stop]`

else you can use `str(url).split(r'/')` to split the url into list of pieces seperated by /

Comment: The Url has the same structure every time. Just different numbers. I tried the two commands but didn't have any luck. Sorry I'm still learning python.